# Vue - how to add custom directive with class define with `export default`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Looking at the documentation for custom directives:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

The following example is given:

```
Vue.directive('pin', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.style.position = 'fixed'
    var s = (binding.arg == 'left' ? 'left' : 'top')
    el.style[s] = binding.value + 'px'
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#dynamicexample',
  data: function () {
    return {
      direction: 'left'
    }
  }
})
```

However, my class is structured with different syntax:

```
export default {
    name: 'dynamicexample',
```

In other words, I'm not using the `new Vue` keyword that is provided in the example.

Where and how do I add the directive in my code so it works?

The `Vue.directive` doesn't work if I just paste it above `export default { name: 'dynamicexample',`. That just causes the app to fail without any warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  directives: {
    focus: {
      inserted: function (el) {
        el.focus()
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="text" v-focus />
</div>
```

You can try to create js file:

```
export const MyDirective {
  name: 'dynamicexample',
    /* your code */
}
```

then, in template where you use it :

```
import MyDirective from './directives/MyDirective.js';

export default {
    directives: {
       MyDirective
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

You can also use

```
Vue.directive('my-directive', MyDirective)
```

to declare it globally.

Comment: Where do I define it globally? In which file? And where in that file?

Comment: Hey mate, try in main.js ,like global filters

Comment: Could you kindly show how to place everything in `directives` dictionary? I don't want a new file. Right now, as soon as I copy `Vue.directive` code above `export default` - the app just doesn't load and without any errors either.